# Is it possible to use binding inside other binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to write something like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextSource, StringFormat='{Binding Path=StringFormat}' }"
```

Or the single way is to have three properties: one for some value and other for string presentation of this value, third for format string. In this case TextBox binds with string representation of value. String presentation changes when format string changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in general and no for your case it is not possible because StringFormat is not Dependency Property.

Binding only works on Dependency Properties.

If you wish that to work create a resource dictionary of type Freezable and let it inherit the actual DataContext. Futhermore use StaticResource extension to set StringFormat in Binding.

StringFormat is not DependencyProperty but it doest accept {StaticResource someKey}.

It's a workaround. But it would work.

Another alternative solution would be attached property.

Attached properties are bindable. You would need to listen to property changed event of your attached property and change the StringFormat inside the handler.